# Asynchronization without Observable

Tags: javascript, angular

In Angular 4 I handle Asychronization by using RXjs Observable.

Now, is there another way to handle Asychronization in Angular 4 without using observable?

Comment: it's call async await https://medium.com/@balramchavan/using-async-await-feature-in-angular-587dd56fdc77

Comment: you can use promise as well

Comment: There is also a great article about this (with clear code samples)... enjoy https://medium.com/@mpodlasin/promises-vs-observables-4c123c51fe13

Comment: I don't understand, do you think that you can't use Observables anymore? Are you trying to do something else?  What exactly is the problem?